# Remove SMTP: from primary email address

Tags: powershell, filter, expression

How do I remove SMTP: from this statement, I want to parse this from the returning email address I have tried several methods and it always makes the entire field return blank.

```
@{Name = "PrimaryEmail"; Expression = { $_.ProxyAddresses.Where( { $_.StartsWith( 'SMTP:') } ) } }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-creplace` operator for this.

```
@{ Name = "PrimaryEmail"
   Expression = { $_.ProxyAddresses.Where( { $_.StartsWith( 'SMTP:') } ) -creplace '^SMTP:'}
}
```

`-creplace` is a case-sensitive version of `replace`. It works with array or string output. `^` matches the beginning of the current string. `SMTP:` is a literal match.